# How to unlike a post that a user has liked in facebook in android

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, restfb

I have written facebook android application using [restfb](http://restfb.com/) .

For unlike a post , Facebook Graph Api says to send an Http delete to https://graph.facebook.com/postid/likes
with the access token

The sample code is

```
String postURL = FacebookAppConstants.GRAPH_API_ACCESS+"/"+postID+
            "/likes&access_token="+FacebookAppConstants.accessToken;

    Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "########Delete URL = "+postURL);
    HttpDelete dislikePost = new HttpDelete(postURL);
    Log.out(logFlag,logTag,"####Method : "+dislikePost.getMethod());


    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(dislikePost);

        Log.out(logFlag, logTag,response.getStatusLine().toString());


    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

While executing i am getting BAD Request 400 from the server.

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

    <HTML><HEAD>
D/SMF     ( 2546): <TITLE>400 Bad Request</TITLE>
D/SMF     ( 2546): </HEAD><BODY>
D/SMF     ( 2546): <H1>Method Not Implemented</H1>
D/SMF     ( 2546): Invalid method in request<P>
D/SMF     ( 2546): </BODY></HTML>
```

What is the solution

Any help

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String postURL = FacebookAppConstants.GRAPH_API_ACCESS+"/"+postID+
            "/likes&access_token="+FacebookAppConstants.accessToken;

    Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "########Delete URL = "+postURL);

    HttpGet dislikePost = new HttpGet(postURL+"&method=DELETE");


    try {
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(dislikePost);
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
        String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
        Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "Body : "+body);           

    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Three things to check:

1. Do you have the `publish_stream` [extended permission](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/permissions/) for that user?
2. Does the user actually like the post already?
3. Is there a proxy server in the middle which could be causing the HTTP DELETE request to be dropped? try 'faking' a DELETE request by making a GET request but adding a parameter, `&method=delete` to the request you're making - the Facebook API will treat this as a 'DELETE' even if it arrives in a GET request

There should be a better error message coming back in the body of the 400 error - if you provide that we can probably help more

Comment: Yes i have the publish_stream extended permission and the user is same who liked the post.  I am seeing only the 400 error.  How to print the body of the error log

Comment: i got how to print the body of response. It is updated in the question. It is saying invalid method in request

Comment: Is the post ID correct? Also, i'm not 100% sure, but I don't think that response is actually coming back from Facebook - I don't think i've seen HTML in the body of the 400 errors from graph.facebook.com - is there a proxy server in the middle which could be causing the HTTP DELETE request to be dropped? try 'faking' a DELETE request by mnaking a GET request but adding a parameter, `&method=delete`

Comment: The post Id is correct since i am using the same postID for liking, the post. There is a proxy server, but how to check whether it is dropping HTTP DELETE. I am able to unlike from the browser. What could be the result if i am faking the DELETE Request>

Comment: Try 'faking' a DELETE request by making a GET request but adding a parameter, `&method=delete`

Comment: How to make HttpGet method as Delete. There is no api to setRequestMethod() in HttpGet. I tried using HttpURLConnection and made the request. Then also i got the same error.

Comment: I don't think you're understanding me - make a HTTP GET request, but in the URL of the request set a parameter called 'method' to the value 'delete' - The Facebook API will treat the request as a DELETE request even though it's actually sent over HTTP GET

Comment: Great.. It worked.. I Send the parameter method with value as Delete as HttpGet Request. Thanks man.. The working code is posted here