# I am trying to unlike a facebook feed which is already liked by the user

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

In an Android app I am trying to unlike a Facebook feed which is already liked by a user, but I am getting "HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request". I am thinking that that may be some error that exists in my url and my url is "https://graph.facebook.com/469111716576852_453729238115100/likes&access_token=CAANGZCSfBfk0BALIuBqJjRxVcwmr0t8nzm3rxC"

and I have given the publish_actions and publish_stream permissions also

I am referring exact code of "[How to unlike a post that a user has liked in facebook in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9324618/how-to-unlike-a-post-that-a-user-has-liked-in-facebook-in-android)"

```
String postURL = FacebookAppConstants.GRAPH_API_ACCESS+"/"+postID+
        "/likes&access_token="+FacebookAppConstants.accessToken;

Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "########Delete URL = "+postURL);

HttpGet dislikePost = new HttpGet(postURL+"&method=DELETE");


try {
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(dislikePost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    String body = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
    Log.out(logFlag, logTag, "Body : "+body);           

} catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

and I am getting a response as:

responce body {"error":{"message":"Unknown path components: /likes&access_token=CAANGZCSfBfk0BAP1Kiu1dRCpcZAVbDd0nZAJZCpZCkTtk3Fx3BqvmU9uzpwpsSSMofWWxmZAoeMFd0VjaeSgzZCGYYPQKoR3dCjIEkyzlQkIrg0pZAYHRwZB5irFvKWtjasut6htyl9U0ZCj3GVI2LOH46BXlHkZBX3d8gz9xijYuAhHD52A1rWShxq7FKEyuh9sBF9RY0cKUP2YKgcjABAXcGM","type":"OAuthException","code":2500}}

Please help me where I am putting the wrong step, your help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you logged in ? You should add the login cookies to the http request

Comment: ya after login only i am trying to hit the url

Answer (score 0):

From the error message, your `postID` seems to be empty. Furthermore you're not doing a `DELETE` request, but a `GET`. Make sure you have the `publish_actions` permission.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/object/likes#delete
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpDelete.html

Code:

```
HttpDelete dislikePost = new HttpDelete(postURL);
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have publish_actions permission and post id also not empty, i tried with HttpDelete dislikePost = new HttpDelete(postURL); also but response is same as previous  -Tobi

Comment: In the error message, there ist no post_id. Are you sure it's in your call? It must be /{post_id}/likes

Comment: the error exist after post_id here is my URL before my cal "https://graph.facebook.com/469111716576852_453729238115100/likes&access_token=CAANGZCSfBfk0BALIuBqJjRxVcwmr0t8nzm3rxC"it is not mentioning the post id

Comment: Your Access Token seems to be incorrect. It's much too short and contains a backslash, which is not allowed.

Comment: i did not find any backslash here =CAANGZCSfBfk0BAP1Kiu1dRCpcZAVbDd0nZAJZCpZCkTtk3Fx3BqvmU9uzpwpsSSMofWWxmZAoeMFd0VjaeSgzZCGYYPQKoR3dCjIEkyzlQkIrg0pZAYHRwZB5irFvKWtjasut6htyl9U0ZCj3GVI2LOH46BXlHkZBX3d8gz9xijYuAhHD52A1rWShxq7FKEyuh9sBF9RY0cKUP2YKgcjABAXcGM

Comment: can you please give me code snippet please if you have